# How to start then stop a CSS animation by pressing a button once, then redo it?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, button

When I start my CSS animation by clicking the button, the result is like what I expected.
But then, **when i click a second time on it, the animation doesn't restart**... :(

This is my code :

```
window.onload = () => {
    let button = document.getElementById('button');
    let votreRole = document.getElementById('role');
    let roles = ['TOP', 'JUNGLE', 'MID', 'ADC', 'SUPPORT'];
    let chargement = document.getElementById('chargement');

// User's clicking > animation starts in 1s > at the end, the role is outputed
    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
        chargement.style.animationPlayState = 'running';
        setTimeout(function (){
            votreRole.innerText = roles[Math.floor(roles.length * Math.random())];
            chargement.style.animationPlayState = 'paused';
        }, 1000)
    })


}
```

Comment: Try removing the class which starts the animation, and then adding it back again?

Comment: Yeah, it worked ! I changed "style.animationPlayState" by "style.animation" and toggled it on "1s 0s" then "none".
Thank you !

I don't understand why "animationPlayState" don't worked btw :/

Comment: I’m not sure either. I’m glad found found a solution. Consider writing it as answer so it may benefit others?

Answer (score 0):

> Try removing the class which starts the animation, and then adding it
> back again?

Answered by *evolutionxbox*